# How to skip test for specific request in postman collection?

Tags: postman-collection-runner

I have a collection and collection-wide tests which are applicable for almost all requests in this collection, except one (let's call it `unique_request`). How can I check request name and skip test, if current request is `unique_request`?

Comment: You could use `pm.info.requestName` to get the current request name, add a conditional statement with your unique name and skip the test if it matches.